# Oracle join nextval from sequence

Tags: oracle, join, sequence

Let's assume

```
Table TARGET {
    ID IDENTITY ...,
    ...
    JOB_NO NUMBER
}
```

My question is, how can I generate the JOB_NO (by means of a sequence) so that all inserts that have been committed in a statement have the same job_no.

The output should be something like for the n-th execution of that insert stmt.

```
ID  ... JOB_NO
1   ... 123
2   ... 123
3   ... 123
```

The following is obviously not working. But what is the correct Oracle syntax?

`INSERT INTO TARGET SELECT A.*, B.* FROM my_source_table A, (SELECT x.nextval from dual) B`

Thanks a lot 
Juergen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could once select the  `NEXTVAL` for every such insert, which increments the `sequence` and then use `CURRVAL` within the `INSERT`.

Let's say this is your sequence

```
create sequence seq START WITH 123 ;
```

Always specify the column names in the `INSERT` to avoid confusion, don't use `select * from`

```
select seq.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL;
INSERT INTO TARGET(JOB_NO,col1,col2,..) 
SELECT seq.CURRVAL, a.col1,a.col2 FROM my_source_table A, ..
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like:

```
insert into target select my_seq.nextval, a.* from source a;
```

Update based on comment below:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Wed Apr 11 12:48:21 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Automatic Storage Management option

SQL> create table a(id number, name varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into a values(1,'Larry');

1 row created.

SQL> c/1/2
  1* insert into a values(2,'Larry')
SQL> c/Larry/Moe
  1* insert into a values(2,'Moe')
SQL> /

1 row created.

SQL> c/2/3
  1* insert into a values(3,'Moe')
SQL> c/Moe/Curly
  1* insert into a values(3,'Curly')
SQL> /

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from a;

        ID NAME
---------- ----------
         1 Larry
         2 Moe
         3 Curly


SQL> create table b as select 1 id, a.id id_a, a.name from a where 1=0;

Table created.

SQL> desc b
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 ID_A                                               NUMBER
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(10)

SQL> create sequence seq_a;

Sequence created.

SQL> insert into b select seq_a.nextval, a.* from a;

3 rows created.

SQL> select * from b;

        ID       ID_A NAME
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1 Larry
         2          2 Moe
         3          3 Curly
```

Comment: I don't think that works. It is creating numbers similar to the PK column; a new value per rows.

Comment: It should work.  I'll update my answer above with a full test case.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I misunderstood your requirement.  My apologies.  The other answer above should do what you want, I think.